# Fixing race condition when sending signal to interrupt system call

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, interrupt

I have a thread that `read()`s from a socket, and I want to be able to stop the thread asynchronously.  The thread pseudocode looks like:

```
int needs_quit = 0;

void *thread_read(void *arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(needs_quit)
        {
            close(sock_fd);
            return NULL;
        }
        int ret = read(sock_fd ...);
        if(ret == EINTR) //we received an interrupt signal to stop
        {
            close(sock_fd);
            return NULL;
        } 
        //do stuff with read data
    }
}
```

The signal handler simply sets `needs_quit` to 1.  Most of the time, this code will work.  But, if a signal arrives after `if(needs_quit)` and before `read(sock_fd ...)`, then `read()` will not be interrupted, and the thread will never stop.  What is the best solution for this problem?

I should point out that I managed to write a working solution with `pthread_cancel`, but as it turns out, I'm not allowed to use that due to compatibility issues.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: which signal are u using?

Comment: SIGUSR1 with pthread_kill

Comment: You can use poll/select/epoll which specify timeout for blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, flipping a flag isn't enough.  There are several approaches I can think of.

### Cancel the thread

No flag needed.

However, [`pthread_cancel`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cancel.html) is not applicable to your environment, as you noted, and many consider it easy to misuse.

### Time-limit the blocking `read()`

Keep the flag, and be minimally patient.

Replacing the `read` with a `select` or `poll` with a short timeout may be good enough.  Do you care if the thread quits "instantly" or within a few seconds?

### `close` or `shutdown` the socket from a signal handler

No flag, but a signal handler that simply `close()`s or `shutdown`s the socket and thus wakes up the `read`.

Closing fds can be dangerous in a multithreaded environment, as the fd can be immediately re-used by another thread's `open` or `pipe` or more exotic calls.  It'd be bad, for instance, to have the signal handler close fd 5 while another thread makes a `pipe` using fd 5 for the readable end, just prior to your `read`.  As @R.. mentions, `shutdown` may or may not work, but, if it does, is safe here.

### Use the *self-pipe trick*

No flag.  Instead your signal handler writes a byte to a non-blocking pipe, and your thread `select`s on both the interesting socket and the readable end of the pipe.  If data arrives (or is already waiting) on the latter, the thread knows it has been signalled.

### Use [`pselect`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pselect.html)

Can use flag.

A functional, atomic `pselect` and thoughtful signal masking will give you reliable EINTR indications of signal delivery.  Warning:  early versions of this call in glibc were *not* atomic.

Comment: `close` from the signal handler most definitely is **not safe** in a multi-threaded program. After the signal handler returns, the `read` will pick up reading on an unrelated file that happened to get assigned the same descriptor number because it was the lowest-available! `shutdown` is safe, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two *general* solutions I know for this sort of problem, short of using thread cancellation:

1. Repeatedly send the signal, with exponential backoff so that you don't keep the target thread from getting scheduled, until the target thread responds that it got the signal.
2. Instead of an interrupting do-nothing signal handler, use a signal handler which calls `longjmp` or `siglongjmp`. Since this results in undefined behavior if you interrupt an async-signal-unsafe function, you need to use `pthread_sigmask` to keep the signal blocked except at times when it's appropriate to act on the signal. The `jmp_buf` or `sigjmp_buf` that you jump (or a pointer to it) should lie in thread-local storage so that the signal handler has access to the one for the correct thread.

In addition, for your specific case of reading from a socket, there may be other approaches that work:

3. Instead of calling `read` directly, first wait for the socket to become readable using `pselect`, which can atomically unblock signals together with waiting. Unfortunately, this precludes using file descriptors whose values exceed `FD_SETSIZE`. On Linux, the `ppoll` function avoids this problem, but it's non-standard. Once `pselect` or `ppoll` has determined that the socket is readable, `read` will not block (unless another thread is able to steal the input first). Another variant on this method is to use the [self-pipe trick](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) with plain `poll` (which is portable).
4. Call `shutdown` on the socket. You would have to test whether this reliably makes the `read` fail on systems you care about, since I don't think it's specified clearly, but this is very likely to work and clean and simple (assuming you don't need the socket anymore after cancelling the operation).